# Help with auto calculated field for dates from another column

Tags: column, date-time, access

I am trying to make a column with expire dates from a date entered in another column. For example I have a column with a date entered for training. I then want another column named expire date that will auto populate the date 2 years after the date entered in the training column. Once I figure that out I need another column after the expire date column with a warning of 90 days when the expire date is. I am having a lot of issues trying to figure out how to make the expire date auto populated the date from the entered date of the training date column. This is in Access by the way please HELP!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Access specific questions are off topic.